# Would fake GET request parameters be considered good opsec?

Tags: web-application, opsec

Let's say I was building a UI and wanted to provide my users with a tad bit more security in cases when their browser history or other personal data on their computer was compromised. If I was to add some fake/decoy query parameters into GET requests (i.e. ‘?id=FaKeID&phone=5551234’) for the sake of throwing off potential bad actors, do you think there could be any benefits to this approach that outweighed the downsides?

Comment: What is the threat model?

Comment: @user253751 Well I didn't have anything specific in mind. For the context of the question I was thinking of any situation were putting out decoy data could be helpful in identifying form submissions and whatnot that were using stolen or unethically obtained information.

Comment: Well if you throw in fake data, you also need to set up honeypots/contact banking companies etc to actually actively look for that fake data to comprehend the hackers or take similar actors. But it's probably going to cover only like 0,1% of all companies rendering your method for achieving this semi-useless. In theory - great idea, in practice - not that really apparently...